# A Macro for outputting HTML into cell in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, macros, microsoft-excel-2016, html

I have a rather extensive spreadsheet that includes specific fields that will need to be input to an HTML code for a website.  I'm wondering if there is a Macro and/or formula that would generate this code automatically that draws from the particular cell fields.  For instance, I need something like this:

```
<b>(=A1)</b>
<p>(=D1)</p>
<p><a href="(=E1)"></a></p>
```

Just for context, in the spreadsheet: A1 = a e-learning course title, D1 = the e-learning course description, E1 = the hyperlink that points to the e-learning course.  I have about 92 separate e-learning courses that I need to generate the same code for, so generating this in Excel for all 92 lines would be ideal.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Hi David, I appreciate your comment...I would certainly provide a starting point if I could, but I'm not even sure where to start (or if what I'm looking for is even possible) which is why I asked the question.  I have tried to Google for a solution, but have not found anything yet.  I thought I'd go directly to the experts at StackOverflow for help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you required is to combine the values of those cells with html tags, then you can try to use the CONCAT function with the following formula in `F2` (presuming that the first Title is in row `A2`):

```
=CONCAT("<b>",A2,"</b><p>",D2,"</p><p><a href=",E2,"></a></p>")
```

Drag the formula to the cells below `F2`.

[image: IMG:]